# Access hidden checkboxes with javascript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a datatable, where each row has a checkbox. I'm trying to add `select-all` functionality to this set of checkboxes, for which I created the following function:

```
function selectAll() {
    $(':checkbox').each(function() {
            this.checked = true;
        });
}
```

This works to select all checkboxes which are currently visible, however, the checkboxes on other pages of the datatable are not selected. I know that there is an issue with these checkboxes in general, since to submit the form and include those checkboxes, I had to add the following function:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    oTable1 = $('#mytable').dataTable();
    $(oTable1.fnGetHiddenNodes()).find('input:checked').appendTo(this);
});
```

So I suspect that in order to check these checkboxes, I will somehow have to append them to the DOM, at least temporarily, check them off, and then remove them from the DOM. Or is there something simpler that I can do?

Comment: you should tell us what these hidden checkboxes once checked are supposed to do? Adding an element to check it then remove it doesn't make much sense

Comment: The checkboxes are part of a form. So when the form is submitted, the second block of code adds them to the DOM so that they will be submitted with the rest of the form. What I'm asking here is how to modify the first block of code so that it will apply to the hidden nodes as well as the visible ones.

Comment: Are you sure the checkboxes in the other pages of the datatable are in the DOM? The datatable widget might just have the data in memory, but only put the current page in the DOM.

Comment: $('.checkbox:hidden').prop('checked', true), will this work?

Comment: Even simpler: `$(":checkbox").prop('checked', true)`

Comment: I don't know if the checkboxes are in the DOM. As the second block of code indicates, it appears that these are "hidden nodes" which may be in memory only. But I want to access those as well (either with the same statement, or with a second statement) to check them off.

Comment: Elie, have you tried using a dom crawler or just dumping the code to see if they exist (I'm assuming they're being created using some serverside language)?

Comment: this is an issue with the datatable and how it hides/shows specific rows. As Barmar indicated, it seems like the plugin is removing the rows from the DOM, and then adding them to DOM as needed. The rows are definitely there when the page is rendered, and I included the second block of code to show what I need to do in order to get these checkboxes submitted with the form (which works).

Comment: a link or a fiddle plz

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this work using the following:

```
oTable1 = $('#mytable').dataTable();
$(oTable1.fnGetNodes()).find(':checkbox').attr('checked',true);
```

As an alternative, you can also use

```
$(oTable1.fnGetFilteredNodes()).find(':checkbox').attr('checked',true);
```

which will apply the "select-all" only to the rows that match the current filter.